# Phonegap navigation ajax in loading pages

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a index with navigation that when clicked will load the pages through ajax instead of going to another html

this is my javascipt:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPage(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'places.html',
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#response").html(html);          

                }
            });     

            return false;       
        }
    </script>
```

i have a href that calls this

```
<a href="" onclick="getPage();">get page</a>
```

this worked for xampp local host but seems to generate error in phonegap

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:129
```

which is the line where the $.ajax is located

Comment: the path to the file in your phonegap project is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait till the device is ready to make an ajax call.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
function getPage(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'places.html',
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#response").html(html);          

            }
        });     

        return false;       
    }
}
```

Comment: ok fixed the problem with the $ not defined but i get a               02-14 09:56:32.180: E/Web Console(20736): Uncaught ReferenceError: getPage is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:127, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

well ajax worked at last needed the complete file address and put it inside documentready

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'file:///android_asset/www/.html/places.html',
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#response").html(html);          

        }
    });
```

another method i found was

```
$("#getProfile").click(function() {
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("GET","file:///android_asset/www/places.html",true);
            ajax.send();

            ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200||ajax.status==0)){               
                    var theHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = theHTML;
                }
            }

        });
```

thanks for the help Malek